# Partially sign a transaction with coinb.in

Tags: multi-signature

I'm trying to generate a 2-of-2 multisig address:

- `pubkey1` and `privkey1` on coinb.in
- `pubkey2` and `privkey2` a bitcoin core client
- I use `createmultisig 2 '''["<pubkey1>", "<pubkey2>']'''` on the core to generate the 2-of-2 multisig address.

.

```
{
  "address": "38RmRDRp4YedPXdh9Vu82akPRtXwvsPeRp",
  "redeemScript": "5221020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ce2102224aca2849ddad9c663c0bcfdac5ce3ca06f784ac8eca83404a4ea4ac61dbe7d52ae"
}
```

I transferred 0.00001BTC to that address in txid [20615db3dcda53ab1e780bb9f2c417c5ad2acfbd475d168b205caba3db401f1a](https://blockchain.info/tx/20615db3dcda53ab1e780bb9f2c417c5ad2acfbd475d168b205caba3db401f1a)  and my goal is to spend this amount from the multisig address:

- I created a raw transaction on the bitcoincore:

.

```
createrawtransaction '''[{ "txid": "20615db3dcda53ab1e780bb9f2c417c5ad2acfbd475d168b205caba3db401f1a", "vout": 1 }]''' '''{ "1BT8tmV9Exfrx7FUjNvLQaUBgpZJaHyXMT": 0.00000900  }'''
```

- I attempt to sign this transaction on coinb.in with `privkey2`:

[image: coinb.in signature]

- I attempt to sign the second transaction on the core:

.

```
signrawtransaction "01000000011a1f40dba3ab5c208b165d47bdcf2aadc517c4f2b90b781eab53dadcb35d6120010000006b483045022100d4367946074622b6e22a936adbded609fba5d2501c603b630d3e2edadcb5bcc402203ac6693fbf2ac7ac4d4234ef19be348b6511a0fcdf5991cb26ac2b695876534c0121020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ceffffffff0184030000000000001976a91472a2a94468e42593656cc9803c7a48c1863fc3e588ac00000000" 
'''[
     {
       "txid": "20615db3dcda53ab1e780bb9f2c417c5ad2acfbd475d168b205caba3db401f1a", 
       "vout": 1, 
       "scriptPubKey": "a91449e688475c78033674b8a645f4339fe41366251587", 
       "redeemScript": "5221020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ce2102224aca2849ddad9c663c0bcfdac5ce3ca06f784ac8eca83404a4ea4ac61dbe7d52ae"}
]'''
'''["privkey2"]'''
```

**Output**

```
{
  "hex": "01000000011a1f40dba3ab5c208b165d47bdcf2aadc517c4f2b90b781eab53dadcb35d6120010000009200473044022015ededd076573807b25a4e7facef5ad132683d54ffde8d28c1dbcab4be8e852e02204a063aec61cf6e1eee4825b9f19566a06f87db02913b283f9281a133127002030100475221020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ce2102224aca2849ddad9c663c0bcfdac5ce3ca06f784ac8eca83404a4ea4ac61dbe7d52aeffffffff0184030000000000001976a91472a2a94468e42593656cc9803c7a48c1863fc3e588ac00000000",
  "complete": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "txid": "20615db3dcda53ab1e780bb9f2c417c5ad2acfbd475d168b205caba3db401f1a",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": "00473044022015ededd076573807b25a4e7facef5ad132683d54ffde8d28c1dbcab4be8e852e02204a063aec61cf6e1eee4825b9f19566a06f87db02913b283f9281a133127002030100475221020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ce2102224aca2849ddad9c663c0bcfdac5ce3ca06f784ac8eca83404a4ea4ac61dbe7d52ae",
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "error": "Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately I can't specify the `pubkeyscript` or `redeemscrit` to coinb.in, so could this be the reason why the signatures are not validating?

**Note:** I can sign the transaction successfully on bitcoin core when I specify both private keys in the command.

Comment: Why can't you provide the `redeemscript` to coinb.in? On the create transaction tab you can paste in the redeemscript instead of an input address.

Comment: Indeed I think that's the root of the issue .. Coinbin does not allow me to specify a redeem script while signing a transaction ... Note that when I sign the transaction on the core first and then do the second signature on coinbin it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve this issue by manually modifying the transaction in javascript before calling coinbin's `sign` method. I've filed an issue with details [here](https://github.com/OutCast3k/coinbin/issues/73). This is how I ended up solving the issue in Javascript (this is kind of a hack, I just specify the same redeemScript for each input, which works for my specific usecase):

```
var rawtx2 = "01000000021a1f40dba3ab5c208b165d47bdcf2aadc517c4f2b90b781eab53dadcb35d61200100000000ffffffff05ec447a886d8711db0d5f4cbf1f61956cf227c82c5594ee195bb179e86faa910100000000ffffffff0138c70000000000001976a91472a2a94468e42593656cc9803c7a48c1863fc3e588ac00000000";


(function partialSignMultisig(window) {
    var coinjs = window.coinjs;
    var wifkey = "<WIFKEYHERE>";
    var script = rawtx2;
    var redeemScript = "5221020150ce6954f0cdcc2c5d57cf249f25eab0eed23e39549c4f06bcb42a37f308ce2102224aca2849ddad9c663c0bcfdac5ce3ca06f784ac8eca83404a4ea4ac61dbe7d52ae";

    var tx = coinjs.transaction();
    var t = tx.deserialize(script);

        // Manually specify scripts for inputs ..
    for (var i = 0; i < t.ins.length; i++) {
        t.ins[i].script = coinjs.script(redeemScript);
    }

    var signed = t.sign(wifkey);
    console.log( signed );


})(window);
```